# Is there a reasoning encrypting a GPL binary where I have to publish the sourcecode?

Tags: encryption, linux, kernel, secure-boot

We're a company selling embedded devices. Our devices use u-boot & Linux, both being GPL and therefore we have to release the sourcecode as used to build our binary.

We're in the process of implementing more security measures (both to increase reliability as well as protection against IP theft), so of cause encryption becomes a topic. Some people call for the encryption of u-boot and kernel (which is supported by the hardware for the bootloader as well as by u-boot for the kernel).

Is there a reasoning in protecting our GPL covered binaries by encryption? We already have secure boot in place (HW for Bootloader, U-Boot for Kernel, ...)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing up concepts. Encryption is to hide something and since you publish the source code anyway there is no reason to hide it. But you tagged "secure boot" and this is more what you probably want in terms of information security.

Secure boot does not care about hiding stuff but it is about making sure that only the intended code runs. It uses cryptography, only not encryption but signatures. Using these signatures it can make sure that only the intended software runs on the device. This way secure boot can be useful to protect the software on the device against manipulation. Note that such protection can be useful for security but also can be used to restrict what users can do with their own hardware in a negative way.

Another way were cryptography is needed is to secure updates. But here again it is not about hiding stuff (encryption) but instead to make sure that these are actual genuine updates from the vendor - using signatures. Here again this can be used for security to protect against malicious updates but also in a negative way to deter power users who like to tinker with the hardware they bought.

Comment: Sorry if the tag was confusing. I'm aware of the topics of integrety (checking the binary is "intact", eg by a CRC), authenticity (eg by checking a signature of an update or during secure boot) and encryption (hiding content). My Question was asked because we have internal discussions and people calling for encrypted kernel (which I agree with you there is no reasoning for). So thanks for supporting my claim, I will update my question to clarify.

Comment: Edited original question for clarification.

Comment: @xavor Whoever wants to encrypt an already public binary has no idea how to secure the devices. Integrity is of course vital, but encrypting a public kernel is silly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point to encrypting a binary that the GPL requires you to release the corresponding source of. There is also no point in encrypting anything if you ship the decryption key in cleartext right next to what you encrypted. "Some people" don't seem to have a good understanding of security and you probably shouldn't listen to them.